# Azure Stream Analytics to Event Hub Very Slow

Tags: performance, azure, partitioning, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

`Stream Analytics` job takes several minutes to output results to an `Event Hub`.

A `Stateless Web API Azure Service Fabric` application is distributed across **8** nodes. The application is very simple, consisting of a single `Controller`, which:

1. Receives a series of `JSON` objects
2. Initialises a series of EventData instances that wrap each `JSON` object
3. Sets the `PartitionKey` property of each EventData isntance to the `machine-name` value
4. Publishes the `JSON` objects as a single batch of `EventData` instances to `Azure Event Hub`

The `JSON` payload is a simple series of `IP addresses` and `time-stamps`, as follows:

```
[{
    "IPAddress": "10.0.0.2",
    "Time": "2016-08-17T12:00:01",
    "MachineName": "MACHINE01"
}, {
    "IPAddress": "10.0.0.3",
    "Time": "2016-08-17T12:00:02",
    "MachineName": "MACHINE01"
}]
```

Once received, the `Event Hub` acts as an input to a `Stream Analytics` job, which executes the following `Query`:

```
SELECT 
    IPAddress, COUNT(*) AS Total, MachineName
INTO 
    Output
FROM 
    Input TIMESTAMP BY TIME
    PARTITION BY PartitionId
GROUP BY 
    TUMBLINGWINDOW(MINUTE, 1), IPAddress, MachineName, PartitionId
HAVING Total >= 2
```

Note that the `Query` is partitioned by `PartitionId`, where `PartitionId` is set to the `machine-name` of the originating `Service Fabric` application. There will therefore be a maximum of **8** `PartitionKeys`

There are **8** individual `Service Fabric` instances, and **8** corresponding `Partitions` assigned to the input `Event Hub`.

Finally, The `Stream Analytics` job outputs the result to a 2nd `Event Hub`. Again, this `Event Hub` has **8** Partitions. The `Stream Analytics` `Query` retains the `machine-name`, which is used as the `PartitionKey` of the output `Event Hub`. The output format is `JSON`.

At best, the process takes **30-60** seconds, and sometimes **several minutes**, for a single HTTP request to reach the output `Event Hub`. The bottleneck seems to be the `Stream Analytics` job, given that the `ASP.NET` application publishes the `EventData` batches in **sub-second** timescales.

**Edit:**

Applying a custom field to `Timestamp By` adds a great degree of latency, when coupled with a `Group By` clause. I have achieved acceptable latency (**1-2 seconds**) when removing the `Timestamp By` clause.

The optimal `Query` is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Count(*) AS Total, IPAddress
FROM
    Input
    Partition by PartitionId
GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(MINUTE, 1), IPAddress, PartitionId
```

However, adding a `Having` clause, results in latency increasing to **10-20** seconds:

```
SELECT
    Count(*) AS Total, IPAddress
FROM
    Input
    Partition by PartitionId
GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(MINUTE, 1), IPAddress, PartitionId
HAVING Total >= 10
```

Without the ability to aggregate data within the `Query`, using a `Having` clause, in a timely fashion, seems to defeat the purpose.

Incidentally, `Streaming Units`, `Partitions`, `Input` and `Output` are configured optimally, as per [this guide to achieving parallelism](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-scale-jobs/) with `Stream Analytics`.